# Additional mail address 'read' from column B

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been using a script that allows me to receive email notification if someone submits a form.
I've been trying to create a way that the submitter of the form could write an email in a form field. Done that, no problem.
Now I'm trying to get that 'hand-written' email to receive the same email notification I get.
The new 'email notification receiver' goes to column C.
How can I do this?
Here is the script I'm using...

```
function sendFormByEmail(e) 
{    

  var email = "myemail@xxxxxxx.com"; 

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
  var message = "";
  var subject = "";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];


  var sugestaoDesporto = e.values[51];
  var sugestaoEntretenimento = e.values[52];
  var sugestaoInformacao = e.values[53];


   message += "Esta transmissão está preparada!\n\n\n";  
  message += headers[51] + "\n\n" + sugestaoEntretenimento + sugestaoDesporto + sugestaoInformacao;
  message += "\n\n\n Esta mensagem foi gerada de forma automática.\n Por favor não responda a este email 
  pois o mesmo não é monitorizado.";

  subject += e.namedValues[headers[3]].toString().replace(",","") + '-' + 
  e.namedValues[headers[11]].toString().replace(",","") + ' ('+ 
  e.namedValues[headers[4]].toString().replace(",","") + ')';

  // Send the email
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 

  // Based off of a script originally posted by Amit Agarwal - www.labnol.org
  // Credit to Henrique Abreu for fixing the sort order
}
```

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 1):

I guess your getting all of your data from the headers row.  So try this:

`MailApp.sendEmail(email + ',' + headers[2], subject, message);`

or possibly:

`MailApp.sendEmail(email + ',' + e.namedValues[headers[2]], subject, message);`

You seem to only be getting data from one row so I don't know where you're storing your posted data when you figure it out the given the recipient field a comma separated value string for multiple recipients.

[sendMail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))

Comment: The second option solved the problem! Thank you so much, Mr. Cooper!!!